# Table has one record per employee per year. How do I select the record for each employee for the latest year for that employee?

Tags: sql

My table has one record per employee per year. How do I select one record per employee getting the latest year for that employee?

Columns are `employee_ref, firstname, lastname, employment_year`.

Each `employee_ref` will have several records, each with different values of `employment_year`

I want to select one record per `employee_ref`, where `employment_year` has the highest value for that `employee_ref` and show the `firstname` and `lastname` from this record.

Though I know SQL, my skills are not up to this one.

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server, mySQL, Postgress, etc?

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a sub-selected:

```
SELECT employee_ref, firstname, lastname
FROM table
WHERE employment_year = (
    SELECT MAX(employment_year)
    FROM table b
    WHERE b.employee_ref = table.employee_ref)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
select firstname, lastname, maxyear
from table join (
select employee_ref, max(employment_year) maxyear
from table
group by employee_ref) temp on table.employee_ref = temp.employee_ref
and employment_year = maxyear
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming employment_year is an integer you could do something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * from (select * from employee where employment_ref=x order by employment_year)
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) for more details.

Comment: The unspecified rdbms may not support that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
with EmployeesMostRecentYear as 
(
SELECT [Employee_ref]
  ,[firstname]
  ,[lastname]
  ,[employment_year]
  ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [Employee_ref],[firstname],[lastname] order by [employment_year] desc) as YearIndex
FROM [TestDb].[dbo].[Employees] E 
)
select * from EmployeesMostRecentYear
where YearIndex = 1
```